# Does Anemia equal poor circulation?

Tags: blood, blood-circulation

Are they one and the same?

Can you be non-anemic and have poor circulation?

Can you have good circulation and be anemic at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

[Anemia](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/anemia/home/ovc-20183131) means decreased ability of the **blood** to carry oxygen. Two examples are iron deficiency anemia and pernicious anemia due to impaired vitamin B12 absorption. You can have anemia and good circulation.

[Poor circulation](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=97614) is a decreased ability of the **circulatory system (heart and arteries)** to deliver blood to all parts of the body. Examples of causes are heart failure, for example after  heart attack, and hardening of arteries in the legs and arms (peripheral artery disease). You can have poor circulation without anemia.